# How to clear contents of certain ranges below specified header?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a worksheet. I want to clear the contents of cells 17-37, 45-60, 65-79; with the column being determined by the header (in Row 15) being equal to the value in Cell B1 of same worksheet. My sheet has columns C-Z to be looked at.

I tried to write a loop, or use other parts of code found online and I am unable to add the lookup so that it will only clear in the column if the value in row 15 of the column matches B1.

EDIT: Here is what I had so far, based on comments but it still will not find my value so cindex returns Error 2042 - checked for leading or trailing spaces.

```vb
Set ws to FORECAST
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FORECAST")
'Set range to search
    Dim hrg As Range
    Set hrg = ws.Range("C15:Z15")
'set range to clear contents
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = ws.Range("17:37,45:60,65:79")

'Set header value to find
    Dim Header As Variant
    Header = ws.Range("B1").Value
    
'hold column where match is found
    Dim cIndex As Variant
    cIndex = Application.Match(Header, hrg, 0)
    
'validate column index and clear
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
        Intersect(hrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn, crg).Clear
    'else no match found; no nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code you've got so far (as text). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73480106/edit) at any time.

Answer (score 1):

### Clear Cells When Matching Header

```vb
Sub ClearColumn()
    
    ' Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Header Range
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = ws.Range("C15:Z15")
    
    ' Clear-Entire-Rows Range
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = ws.Range("17:37,45:60,65:79")

    ' Header (Value)
    Dim Header As Variant: Header = ws.Range("B1").Value
    
    ' Column Index (index of the matching cell (column)
    ' of the Header range (if a match))
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(Header, hrg, 0)
    
    ' Validate the Column index and clear.
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then ' match found
        Intersect(hrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn, crg).Clear
    'Else ' no match found; do nothing
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks close, however my cIndex is coming up empty.  I'm trying to troubleshoot myself - but any ideas? I did modify the WS to be ws=worksheets("FORECAST") Which is the name of my sheet.  It recognizes the header value but not matching it

Comment: You may want to qualify the worksheet e.g. if the code is in the workbook containing the `FORECAST` worksheet, you should use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FORECAST")`. The rest of the code needs to stay intact (the loop in your attempt is a mistake). If still an obvious match cannot be found, check the headers for leading or trailing spaces. BTW, `Application.Match` is case-insensitive i.e. `a = A`. `cIndex` will either be an error value (e.g. `Error 2042`) or a number from 1 to 24 (the number of cells (columns) of the header range). Check it with e.g. `Debug.Print cIndex`.

Comment: Yes, the Error is 2042. I have checked for leading/trailing spaces. When I open the workbook and Ctrl+F I can find both cells - the one in the Header cell; and the hrg.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

```
Sub ClearByHeaderName()

    Dim criteriaCell    As Range
    Dim headerCells     As Range
    Dim headerCell      As Range
    Dim isColumnCleared As Boolean
    
    Set criteriaCell = Range("B1")
    If criteriaCell.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Provide column name in B1!", vbExclamation
        End
    End If
    Set headerCells = Range("C15:Z15")
    
    For Each headerCell In headerCells
        If headerCell.Value = criteriaCell.Value Then
            ClearDataCells headerCell
            isColumnCleared = True
        End If
    Next
    
    If isColumnCleared Then
        MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Cannot find column '" & criteriaCell.Value & "'!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ClearDataCells(headerCell As Range)

    With headerCell.EntireColumn
        .Rows("17:37").Clear
        .Rows("45:60").Clear
        .Rows("65:79").Clear
    End With

End Sub
```